# In F#, how to always execute a bound Async process?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have the following methods in F#:

```
let GetAllPatientNamesAsync() =
        async {
                let data = context.GetAllPatientNamesAsync() 
                return! Async.AwaitTask data
            }

let getAllPatientNames  = Async.RunSynchronously (FsNetwork.GetAllPatientNamesAsync())
```

This works the *FIRST* time:

```
{ m with names = getAllPatientNames}
```

But once getAllPatientNames has a value, calling it again **does not** execute the Async.RunSynchronously (FsNetwork.GetAllPatientNamesAsync()) -- rather getAllPatientNames returns its original value.

Since FsNetwork.GetAllPatientNamesAsync() is accessing the database, which is changing, after the first read getAllPatientNames is wrong.

Ofcourse, this works correctly no matter how many times I use it:

```
{ m with names = Async.RunSynchronously (FsNetwork.GetAllPatientNamesAsync()) }.
```

How should I write

```
let getAllPatientNames  = Async.RunSynchronously (FsNetwork.GetAllPatientNamesAsync())
```

such that it *ALWAYS* executes the Async process?  What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that

> getAllPatientNames

is a a value and not a function. Make a it a function by changing it like below

```
let getAllPatientNames () = Async.RunSynchronously (FsNetwork.GetAllPatientNamesAsync())
```